# Why my C# socket program has lots of \device\afd handles?

Tags: c#, tcpsocket, handle-leak

I've written a tcp socket prgram that working with sockets asyncoronously.

This is some part of my code:

```
public void main()
{
   var e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
   e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(e_Completed);
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {                        
         allDone.Reset();
         mySocket.AcceptAsync(e);
         allDone.WaitOne();                       
   });
}

public void e_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
     var socket = (Socket)sender;
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleTcpRequest, e.AcceptSocket);
     e.AcceptSocket = null;
     socket.AcceptAsync(e);
}

public void HandleTcpRequest(object state)
{
    var mySocket = (Socket)state;
    try
    {
       //do some codes and work with mySocket 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        mySocket.Close();
        mySocket.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I've seen lots of \device\afd in process explorer in my process.  I've read and searched a lot about this and found that it is related to the Ancillary Function Driver and the Transport Driver Interface.  How can I resolve this handle leak?

==========> edited my code:

Edited to accept only 10 sockets in sync way.

Feel that program is more faster, but when push my finger on Ctrl+F5, find that
there are more than 10 \device\afd in process explorer and when continuing too push, see more \device\afd, but lower that above code.

```
 mySocket.Listen(10);
 while (true)
 {                                                
      using (Socket so = mySocket.Accept())
      {
            HandleTcpRequest(so);
      }   
 }
```

Comment: You posted 3 methods that are completely unrelated to each other. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You code never teminates.  Noting is setting the allDone waithandle.  So you think the program is closing when it is not really closing.  See following posting for a suggestion of fixing issue : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3295e38d-2267-425a-a7f8-9e6035331e53/how-to-capture-closing-of-c-console-apps?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've edited my code

Comment: @jdweng  I've edited my code

Comment: No offense intended, but your mix of thread pool code, synchronous waiting on handles and tasks suggests to me that you're using `SocketAsyncEventArgs` when you have not yet mastered the intricacies of network code to the point where you can profitably use it. Consider using `TcpClient` in an asynchronous manner, or, if you do need to go beyond that, the async versions of the `Socket` methods. `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is advanced stuff that should really only go in servers that need to process a ton of load and have exhausted other obvious avenues of optimization, as it's not the easiest API.

Comment: I don't know why you need the Task.Factory.  The code runs asynchronously already and you have the WaitHandle to block so the program does't terminate.   The Task.Factory is crating the memory leak because the Task.Factory lets the process continue after the application closes.

Comment: For `TcpClient` in my remark above, read `TcpListener`, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've edited my code, please look at description in edited in lower part. Thanks

Comment: @jdweng I've used Task.Factory because multiple IPs may bind in same program.

Comment: `using (Socket)`. Dispose your disposable resources. Asynchronous code makes this trickier (on occasion), but doesn't remove the basic requirement. Beyond that, there is simply no need to fret about the number of handles unless you can demonstrate that they continuously increase over the course of running your program, despite you disposing of everything properly. In particular, there could be a bunch of preallocated or cached objects that won't disappear until your process ends.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've forgotten to write that in finally block I use mySocket.Dispose(); Isn't it enough?

Comment: I was only talking about your last sample.

Comment: Each IP will have it own instance of the process so putting it in a Task.Factory will do nothing except create a memory leak.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've changed last part, but stil when pushing ctrl+F5, \device\afd handles increase, and when open new tab to send a new request, it waits until first tab (which ctrl+F5 pushed for one minute) loads and answers second tab.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Any idea about removing same requests from same client that pushing ctrl+F5? Don't want to waste server resources and put other clients in queue. Is there any standard way that many webservers doing that? Or I should add some configuration to socket ?